# Python.exe has stopped working - Windows 10 - etree.pyd

Tags: python, windows-10, lxml

I have a python 2.7.11 (32bit) installed on two Windows 10 machines (64 bit os).  Recently, on both machines, the application raised the "python.exe has stopped working" error dialog when running a web scraper using `bs4` and `lxml`. The error would occur after a minute or two of running correctly (successfully parsing a bunch of web pages).

To isolate the problem, I ran it in a virtual environment with only the needed modules installed. Same issue.

The windows events log references `etree.pyd` on both machines:

```
Faulting application name: python.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x56634a05
Faulting module name: etree.pyd, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x56f0edd1
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000fa43b
Faulting process id: 0x2e78
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1ce087cff81b9
Faulting application path: C:\Projects\VENVS\hhs_v5_venv\Scripts\python.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Projects\VENVS\hhs_v5_venv\lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.pyd
Report Id: f8a4345e-1d59-44d7-be66-f0ff04abbe2e
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I can't find anything recent on `lxml` or `etree.pyd` crashing python in Windows 10.  Anyone else having similar trouble?

Update: I did not figure out why `lxml` was causing the problem, but I did switch parsers and now the script works perfectly:

old:
`html_node = BeautifulSoup(html_to_parse, "lxml")`

new:
`html_node = BeautifulSoup(html_to_parse, "html.parser")`

Comment: Can it be your connection? are you using a proxy?

Comment: What version of lxml?

Comment: @MarcelWilson looks like 3.6.0

Comment: @BubbleHacker no proxies. Thanks!